# valgrind sscanf issues with arguments

Tags: c, memory, arguments, valgrind

Im writing this program in c89 that reads the files however i keep getting segmentation fault
ive run it by `valgrind --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all -v ./program`  and it pointed to the  two sscanf lines leaks
to run the program, it is two file names

./program cat.txt dog.txt
and complies by a make file
I have free'd them and set to null after and i still get these issues, i have attached a picture of my [![valgrind errors here][1]][1]

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

char* cat = (char*)malloc(12 * sizeof (char));
char* dog = (char*)malloc(12 * sizeof (char));
/*float sleepTime;*/

/*if (argc != 4)
{
    printf("Error - Enter file names");
}*/


sscanf(argv[1], "%s", cat);
sscanf(argv[2], "%s", dog);
sleepTime = atof(argv[3]);

readFile(cat);
readFile(dog);

free(cat);
free(dog);
cat = NULL;
dog = NULL;
```

}

i tried to comment things out, however still no luck
any help would be appreciated

Comment: The code is incomplete. Please provide a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)  - include all missing code, the input files and the exact command line used to run the program.

Comment: Also please include the actual Valgrind output.

Comment: By the way, what is the reason you use dynamic allocation here? Why not use plain arrays?

Comment: On another note, the `%[]` format specifier is just that, `%[]`. There's no `s` in the format. That aside, why use `sscanf` here anyway? The command-line arguments shouldn't have a newline in them anyway.

Comment: `./program` if that really is how you invoke the program then of course it seg faults. There are no command line args in which case `argv[1]` and `argv[2]` would be undefined values.

Comment: The Valgrind output doesn't show leaks, but rather that you use invalid pointers. Like the `NULL` pointer that `argv[1]` should be when you don't provide any actual arguments. Perhaps you should take some time to refresh how the `argc` and `argv` arguments work?

Comment: i dont understand what needs to be changed

Answer (score 1):

Ok from looking at the valgrind log aswell as reading what you wrote I gather this:

1. You are building with a makefile, which should set the compiler arguments dog.txt and cat.txt, which are then written `cat` and `dog`.
2. The valgrind log says `Address 0x0 is not ...` in main when calling `sscanf()`.
   This means that there is a null pointer as it is pointing to an invalid memory address, being used in the `sscanf()` call.
3. So either the make build fails to properly compile with the arguments or the memory allocation of `cat` and `dog` is not successful.

.

To check validity:
I would recommend writing some assertions or writing a function to check if a pointer is vaild and call it and check your pointers, namely `cat` , `dog` and `argv[index]` just before calling `sscanf()`.

[https://ptolemy.berkeley.edu/~johnr/tutorials/assertions.html](https://ptolemy.berkeley.edu/%7Ejohnr/tutorials/assertions.html)

https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/MEM10-C.+Define+and+use+a+pointer+validation+function

A good and simple example of pointer validation from the above link:

```
int valid(void *ptr) {
    return (ptr != NULL); // 1 valid, 0 invalid
}
```

To fix eventual makefile issues I think we would need to see the makefile in question, but if that can't be done for some reason then these might be of interest:

[Command-line arguments via Makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23206467/command-line-arguments-via-makefile)

[How to pass argument from Makefile to a program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48261350/how-to-pass-argument-from-makefile-to-a-program)

Edit:

I checked the updated valgrind log on the question and noticed that the reachable memory that is in `readFile()`.
To fix that issue you would need to define a function that properly closes the file. As you never close the files, leaving them hanging in memory causing your reachable memory warning.

Comment: i have changed a few codes and updated myvalgrind code

Comment: Re-read my answer as it still applies. You should especially read the two links regarding assertions and pointer validation. 

And if your pointer validation shows that your argv[1], argv[2], argv[3] are equal to NULL (which is highly likely), then read the two links at the bottom of my answer, which are links to relevant questions with good answers

Comment: Updated my answer slightly with an example of pointer validation from one of the links, hopefully it will make it clear how you could go about checking if a pointer is valid

Comment: i have checked my pointers are valid, they've all returned with a 1

Comment: I didn't notice that the actual valgrind logs were updated at first, I just made an edit at the bottom of my answer that would fix the reachable memory warning.